# Left-Outer-Join to same table with Linq/EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I need to create a left-outer-join to the same table:

```
SELECT Top(20) s.Id as ParentId, CASE WHEN cr.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END AS HasChangeRequest
FROM [Platos.PRM.Dev].[dbo].[Section] s
left outer join [Section] cr on cr.ParentSectionId = s.Id
```

For this I wrote the following Linq statement:

```
var query = from section in this.prmDbContext.Sections
        join changeRequest in this.prmDbContext.Sections.Where(x => x.ParentSection != null && !x.IsInactive) on section.Id equals changeRequest.ParentSection.Id into changeRequestJoin
        from changeRequest in changeRequestJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new 
        {
            Id = section.Id,
            HasChangeRequest = changeRequest != null
        };

var result = query.Take(20).ToList();
```

The linq statement works and deliver the correct result, but is very slow.

SQL statement: some millisconds - LINQ statement: 5 seconds

Could anyone tell me, why the performance with this linq statement is bad?

Thanks!

**Update:**
After adding a navigation property (ChangeRequests) I update the query to the following linq statement:

```
var query = from section in this.prmDbContext.Sections        
select new 
{
    Id = section.Id,
    HasChangeRequest = section.ChangeRequests.Any()
};
var result = query.Take(20).ToList();
```

Now the EntityFramework creates the following sql query:

```
SELECT 
[Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Limit1].[C2] AS [C2]
FROM ( SELECT TOP (20) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    1 AS [C1], 
    CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Section] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[ParentSectionId]
    )) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C2]
    FROM [dbo].[Section] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Limit1]
```

Now the query is faster, but still slower than the left-outer-join from the native sql query. So is it possible, to optimize the linq statement?

Comment: You seem to be mixing navigation properties (which generate implicit joins) with explicit joins. Check the generated SQL, it should be quite different from the shown SQL query. But once you have `ParentSection` navigation property, don't you have the related collection navigation property (something like `public ICollection<Section> ChildSections { get; set; }`)?

Comment: Your SQL and LINQ implement entirely different queries - why shouldn't they differ in execution time?

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for the tip. I add the navigation property and the following mapping: `this.HasMany(s=>s.ChangeRequests).WithOptional(x=>x.ParentSection);` I update the query to the following statement: `var query = from section in this.prmDbContext.Sections select new { Id = section.Id, HasChangeRequest = section.ChangeRequests.Any() }` Now the query is faster, but the join takes still three seconds, which is in my opinion too long. So have you a further performance optimization? Thanks!

Comment: May we see the generated SQL query after the change (e.g. `query.Take(20).ToString()`)? Btw, you can **update** your question as many times as you wish. Just don't post the updates as answers or comments.

Comment: @IvanStoev I add an update to my question

Comment: Thanks. It looks good to me (hope the `ParentSectionId` column in the table is indexed), the query optimizer should generate similar plan to the join query. Please note that the SQL query is not *functionally* equivalent, since it multiplies the "parent" record with "children" records and takes 20 from the result, which probably is wrong.

Comment: I found out that the generated query is fast. The problem is, that with the `.Any()` statement the translation to the query cause the performance issue. So is there a way to improve the performance to translate linq to database query?